# how to start logstash-forwarder as a service in Windows?

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

i am at the moment using a vbs script to do this

This script works perfectly for some hours and stops for no reason. Can anyone point to me what is wrong with the script? How do i add logstash-forwarder to run as a service? I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to do this?

any help is appreciated.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmds=WshShell.RUN("E:\logstash\logstash-forwarder.exe --config E:\logstash\conf.txt", 0, True)
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logstash-forwarder as Windows Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610991/logstash-forwarder-as-windows-service)

Comment: Sorry but i wan't to do it without installing any other tools? is it possible to do this with the vbs script? can anyone point me why does it stop working after sometime.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below batch command. You don't need to install nssm. You just need the nssm exe on the current directory.

```
#install logstash-forwarder as service
c:\elk> nssm "install" "logstash-forwarder" "c:\elk\logstash-forwarder_windows_386.exe" 

c:\elk> nssm "set" "logstash-forwarder" "AppDirectory" "c:\logstash-forwarder" 

c:\elk> nssm "set" "logstash-forwarder" "AppStopMethodSkip" "6"
```

Comment: This answer is partially complete. I have added a line in another answer which adds AppParameters so you can add the configuration path.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to deal with this issue and was able to resolve. I basically used @VinothNair's instructions from his answer however it was missing "AppParameters" which contains the "-config logstash-forwarder.conf" argument which is required for this to work.

I created a script called createService.bat in C:\temp\logstash-forwarder. I also copied the nssm.exe file into the same directory. You can download nssm from https://nssm.cc/release/nssm-2.24.zip. Extract and copy nssm-2.24\win64\nssm.exe to the same directory.

```
@echo off
set BASE_DIR=C:\temp\logstash-forwarder
nssm install Logstash-Forwarder "%BASE_DIR%\logstash-forwarder.exe"
nssm set Logstash-Forwarder AppDirectory "%BASE_DIR%"
nssm set Logstash-Forwarder AppStopMethodSkip "6"
nssm set Logstash-Forwarder AppParameters "-config %BASE_DIR%\logstash-forwarder.conf"
```

Comment: I don't like the fact that you need to use nssm. This should be simple with sc create however I haven't had any luck with the -config argument.