# How to send log data into the Log Analysis service on IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, log-analysis

I found these is guide for Ubuntu OS. But how about other Linux OS(Don't support apt-get) and Windows OS ?

Comment: Sending on-premises data to a space in the IBM Cloud:https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/CloudLogAnalysis/how-to/send-data/send_data_mt.html#send_data_mt

Comment: Is your question still open? Anything specific?

Comment: @data_henrik  Yes, still open. I have not found a method to send log to Log Analysis on Windows System.

Comment: I use Log Analysis in some ways, but not Windows. The input processing is based on logstash, so this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610991/logstash-forwarder-as-windows-service

Comment: @data_henrik I tried to use logstash-forwarder or Filebeat to send logs to Log Analysis, but there is no place to set access token for Log Analysis. I think Log Analysis Service modified Logstash interface. And Log Analysis Service provide mt-logstash-forwarder for us to send logs, and I think mt-logstash-forwarder was implemented based on logstash-forward, but modified the configuration and output interface to fit Log Analysis.